# Script Error when run https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/image_retraining/label_image.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

I try to retrain Inception's Final Layer for New Categories by reference the following [doc](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/tensorflow-for-poets/index.html?index=..%2F..%2Findex#0)

- My OS: Windows 10 X64 Enterprise
- Python 3.6.2 by Anaconda 4.4
- Tensorflow : 1.3.0 (CPU-Only Version)

When I use new images that collect by me and finish the training, I use following commend to test, but failed!

```
(tensorflow13) C:\Users\James\Tensorflow\model-retrain\tensorflow-for-poets-2\scripts>python .\label_image.py --image c:\Users\James\Tensorflow\sample_img\Panda001.jpg --graph c:\Users\James\Tensorflow\model-retrain\tensorflow-for-poets-2\scripts\retrained_graph.pb --labels C:\Users\James\Tensorflow\model-retrain\tensorflow-for-poets-2\scripts\retrained_labels.txt
```

Error Message:

```
2017-09-01 09:27:46.902115: I C:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\nightly-win\M\windows\PY\36\tensorflow\core\platform\cpu_feature_guard.cc:137] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX AVX2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\label_image.py", line 120, in <module>
    input_operation = graph.get_operation_by_name(input_name);
  File "C:\Users\James\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tensorflow13\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 3225, in get_operation_by_name
    return self.as_graph_element(name, allow_tensor=False, allow_operation=True)
  File "C:\Users\James\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tensorflow13\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 3097, in as_graph_element
    return self._as_graph_element_locked(obj, allow_tensor, allow_operation)
  File "C:\Users\James\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\tensorflow13\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 3157, in _as_graph_element_locked
    "graph." % repr(name))
KeyError: "The name 'import/input' refers to an Operation not in the graph."
```

Does anyone has same problem ?

Answer (score 0):

For some reason retrained_graph.pb doesn't have the input the script expects it to have. Probably it was built slightly differently from what the tutorials expect (specifically around how the meta graph was imported).

Answer (score 0):

[Updated link to script](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/label_image/label_image.py)

The problem here is that your inputs/outputs are probably wrong, the script is using this ones:

```
  input_name = "file_reader"
  output_name = "normalized"
```

If you trained this model you might need to find your inputs/outputs as they are likely to be different.

I dont know the best way to find this out but this code has help me a before:

```
import tensorflow as tf
frozen='/tensorflow/mobilenets/mobilenet_v1_1.0_224.pb'
gf = tf.GraphDef()
gf.ParseFromString(open(frozen,'rb').read())
[n.name + '=>' +  n.op for n in gf.node if n.op in ( 'Softmax','Placeholder')]
[n.name + '=>' +  n.op for n in gf.node if n.op in ( 'Softmax','Mul')]
```